# Vega Lite script doesn't retrieve data from extrenal url

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I created this public json data url: https://json.extendsclass.com/bin/fe8c1cc6bebf

Now I want to incluse this url in vega script, but its not working.
Note that it's working with data 'inside the script':

Not working:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {"url": "https://json.extendsclass.com/bin/fe8c1cc6bebf"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Working:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: "The editor does support absolute data URLs but you need to make sure that the server supports CORS. We could definitely improve the error handling. "

https://groups.google.com/g/vega-js/c/bUm9r0wu5E8